# vimeo video JS - how to speed up video start?

Tags: javascript, video, vimeo

After clicking the PLAY button, the video needs 3 seconds to start (after clicking there

is a white background and then the video starts), what can I do to prevent this pause?

Thank you

````
```https://jsfiddle.net/kmartynak/hz6fj5ud/41/```
````